# Does a MySQL backup save custom functions, events, and queries?

Tags: mysql, mysql-event, mysql-backup, mysql-function

I successfully did a backup of my database, dropped the DB in workbench and created a new one, and attempted to restore it. First, it didn’t restore until I ran the creation of a custom function first (which is something I use in multiple views), and when I did restore it, the event I created wasn’t present.

> FUNCTION library.daysout does not exist

I can understand why a query I had open would not be restored (although if you can tell me how to do that, please do,) but how can I make sure my custom function and event restore (especially since the DB doesn’t restore till I run the creation of the function before)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

A default database dump or export does not include stored procedures or stored functions by default.

MySQL Workbench has a checkbox to include stored procedures and functions in an export. You have to check this, and it's not checked by default.

[image]

This option is shown in the screenshots in the manual here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-admin-export-import-management.html Although it isn't described clearly in the text.

Likewise if you use the command-line `mysqldump` tool, you must use the `--routines` option to include stored procedure and stored function definitions in the export. This option is documented here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_routines

Comment: Thanks! I've been using command line, didn't see the checkbox in workbench. Are events similarly included if we check dump stored procedures and functions?

Comment: Check the documentation links I gave. The answers are there!